# How to know if the client call connection close on TcpListener?

Tags: c#

I wrote simple application that using TcpListener. 
The application is wait till some client will connect - and while the client is connected the application will listen to his sending stream.

In the code - i using while loop to check if the client is connected. 
But event when i close the connection on the client side i get connected == true

But .. on the client close => i see that the server get byte stream with byte.length == 0

Code ...

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5501);
        tcpListener.Start(1);       // listen one client only

        TcpClient client = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

        NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();

        while (client.Connected)    // after connected => this is always true .. event if i close the connection on the client side 
        {
            // do something ... 
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("No Connected");
}
```

Comment: it says in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that *Because the Connected property only reflects the state of the connection as of the most recent operation, you should attempt to send or receive a message to determine the current state.*. So you should try to send/receive first, and then check. `0` to my knowledge means that the connection was closed.

Comment: Have you tried tcpListener.Stop() after closing your client?

Comment: wrap your networkStream.ReadAsync in a try catch, it returns a Task<int> after the try catch check if it returns 0 if it does the client is disconnected, then break out of the while if its 0, your while loop should be while(true)

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly demonstrates the problem, it's not possible to answer. That said, you wrote _"on the client close => i see that the server get byte stream with byte.length == 0"_. If by that you mean that the server reads from the stream and gets 0 as the count of bytes returned from the read operation, then the client is in fact correctly _shutting down_ the connection (not just calling `Close()`), and the 0 result on the read operation is exactly how the server knows that happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a connection-*oriented* protocol, but the connection still is a virtual one - the only way to know that the other party is still connected is by successfully sending or receiving a message to/from it. This is why the `Connected` property may give false positives.

The 0-byte message means that the client has sent all their data and has closed (the send direction of) the socket. At that point the client still is connected, waiting for a 0-byte message back from the server (which is automatically sent when you close the server socket).

Of course in case of a network failure you would never receive that 0-byte message, but you would receive (eventually) a `SocketException` instead.

See this [WinSock FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/newbie.html#howclose) for more information about the shutdown process.